# Type coercion function (a "safe cast")

Tags: c++, converting

Usually in C++, the language rules automatically convert types as necessary. For example, I can pass a pointer-to-derived in place of a pointer-to-base, and the same with references.

There are occasions where one needs to specify a type to which a value should be coerced, but less strongly than a cast.  Some cases where we might need to do this include

- two-step conversion, where we need to coerce to an intermediate type,
- providing consistent arguments for function template type deduction,
- adding const and/or volatile (but not casting them away),
- ensuring that both alternatives of `?:` are compatible.

My first attempt at this was [*An up-cast for C++*](/q/282077/75307), but there were serious problems with that.  I've improved the motivational context, ensured that narrowing of primitive types and use of `explicit` conversions are prevented, and added tests.

That was pretty simple:

> ```
> #include <utility>
>
> namespace coercion
> {
>     template<typename From, typename To>
>     concept coercible = requires(From&& value, void (*f)(To)) {
>         f({std::forward<From>(value)});
>         f(std::forward<From>(value)); // prevents base&& → derived&&
>     };
>
>     template<typename To, coercible<To> From>
>     constexpr To coerce_to(From&& value)
>     {
>         return {std::forward<From>(value)};
>     }
> }
> ```

However, a review of the first attempt said:

> Having to remember the right cv-qualification and adding a reference
> is a bit annoying.  I'd just want to write `up_cast<Base>(foo)` and have
> it return a `const Base&` or `Base&` or maybe even a `volatile Base*`,
> depending on what `foo` is.

It's not possible to automatically reference-qualify the result type without conflicting with use for widening value types, but I was able to add the relevant cv-qualification with this more complex version:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace coerce
{
    // copy qualifications across
    template<typename From, typename To>
    using copy_const =
        std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<From>,
                           std::add_const_t<To>,
                           To>;

    template<typename From, typename To>
    using copy_volatile =
        std::conditional_t<std::is_volatile_v<From>,
                           std::add_volatile_t<To>,
                           To>;

    template<typename From, typename To>
    using copy_cv = copy_const<From, copy_volatile<From, To>>;


    template<typename From, typename To>
    struct result { using type = To; };

    template<typename From, typename To>
    struct result<From*,To*> {
        using type = std::add_pointer_t<
            copy_cv<From,
                    typename result<std::remove_cv_t<From>, To>::type>>;
    };

    template<typename From, typename To>
    struct result<From&,To&> {
        using type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<
            copy_cv<From,
                    typename result<From, To>::type>>;
    };

    template<typename From, typename To>
    struct result<From&&,To&&> {
        using type = std::add_rvalue_reference_t<
            copy_cv<From,
                    typename result<From, To>::type>>;
    };



    template<typename From, typename To>
    using result_t = result<From, To>::type;

    template<typename From, typename To>
    concept coercible = requires(From&& value, void (*f)(result_t<From,To>)) {
        f({std::forward<From>(value)});
        f(std::forward<From>(value));
    };

    template<typename To, coercible<To> From>
    constexpr result_t<From,To> to(From&& value)
    {
        return {std::forward<From>(value)};
    }
}
```

The compile-time test suite is quite substantial:

```
#include <cstdint>

// Using concepts for these tests improves error diagnostics
template<typename From, typename To>
concept can_coerce =
    requires(From f) { coerce::to<To>(std::forward<From>(f)); };

template<typename From, typename To, typename Expected>
concept coerce_result_fails = std::is_same_v<Expected, void> && !can_coerce<From, To>;

template<typename From, typename To, typename Expected>
concept coerce_result_passes = coerce::coercible<From, To>
    && std::same_as<coerce::result_t<From, To>, Expected>;

template<typename From, typename To, typename Expected>
concept coerce_result_is =
    coerce_result_fails<From, To, Expected> || coerce_result_passes<From, To, Expected>;


// widening (or preserving) integer conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int, int, int>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<bool, bool, bool>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<bool, char, char>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const std::uint8_t&, std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<std::uint16_t, std::int32_t, std::int32_t>); // safe sign change

// no narrowing integer conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<char, bool, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<std::uint32_t, std::int16_t, void>); // smaller range
static_assert(coerce_result_is<std::int16_t, std::uint32_t, void>); // unsafe sign change


// pointers - can add cv-qualification
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*, int*, int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*, const int*, const int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*, volatile int*, volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*, const volatile int*, const volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int*, const volatile int*, const volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int*, const volatile int*, const volatile int*>);
// existing cv-qualification is retained
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int*, int*, const int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int*, int*, volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int*, int*, const volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int*, const int*, const volatile int*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int*, volatile int*, const volatile int*>);

// lvalue references
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&, const int&, const int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&, volatile int&, volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&, const volatile int&, const volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int&, const volatile int&, const volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int&, const volatile int&, const volatile int&>);
// existing cv-qualification is retained
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int&, int&, const int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int&, int&, volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&, int&, const volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&, const int&, const volatile int&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&, volatile int&, const volatile int&>);

// rvalue references
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&&, const int&&, const int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&&, volatile int&&, volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&&, const volatile int&&, const volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int&&, const volatile int&&, const volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int&&, const volatile int&&, const volatile int&&>);
// existing cv-qualification is retained
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const int&&, int&&, const int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile int&&, int&&, volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&&, int&&, const volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&&, const int&&, const volatile int&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile int&&, volatile int&&, const volatile int&&>);

// references to pointers
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&, int*&, int*&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&&, int*&&, int*&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&, const int*&, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&, volatile int*&, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&&, const int*&&, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int*&&, volatile int*&&, void>);

// no lvalue to rvalue conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int&, int&&, void>);

// no prvalue to lvalue conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int, int&, void>);
// but lifetime-extending is okay
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int, const int&, const int&>);
// and so is value to rvalue-ref
static_assert(coerce_result_is<int, int&&, int&&>);


// up-casts and down-casts

struct Base {
    // Prevent accidental object slicing to this base
    Base(auto const&) = delete;
    explicit Base(std::derived_from<Base> auto const& other)
        : Base{coerce::to<Base&>(other)} {}
};
struct Derived : Base {};

static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base, Base, Base>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base, Derived, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived, Derived, Derived>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived, Base, void>); // slicing constructor is explicit

static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived*, Base*, Base*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived*, const Base*, const Base*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const Derived*, Base*, const Base*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile Derived*, Base*, volatile Base*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const Derived*, volatile Base*, const volatile Base*>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile Derived*, const Base*, const volatile Base*>);

static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived&, Base&, Base&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const volatile Derived&, const volatile Base&, const volatile Base&>);

static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived&&, Base&&, Base&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<const Derived&&, Base&&, const Base&&>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<volatile Derived&&, Base&&, volatile Base&&>);

// no down-casts
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base*, Derived*, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base&, Derived&, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base&&, Derived&&, void>);

// no lvalue to rvalue conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Base&, Base&&, void>);
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived&, Base&&, void>);

// no prvalue to lvalue conversions
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived, Base&, void>);
// but lifetime-extending is okay
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived, const Base&, const Base&>);
// and so is value to rvalue-ref
static_assert(coerce_result_is<Derived, Base&&, Base&&>);
```

I'm particularly interested in additional tests, especially if they expose weaknesses in the implementation.

Comment: This looks very good. However, it fails to compile with Clang: missing `typename` in the declaration of `result_t` (easy fix), but more importantly the last two references-to-pointers asserts fail to compile. I don't know why though.

Comment: That's useful information.  I used GCC 12, for the record.  Not sure why it differs or which is more correct.

Comment: @TobySpeight GCC is correct, as of C++20 (which I presume because of the use of concepts). This is a “[Down with `typename`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3)” thing; `typename` is no longer necessary in type aliases as of C++20 (but it’s not incorrect to add it). Clang will apparently support this in v16, which I don’t think is out yet.